# vertex array with smoothness

Tags: c++, vertex-arrays

I'm using vertex array to draw 2d geometry,
but I can't achieve smoothness.

This is the code I'm using:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, shared_colors);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, shared_vertex);

glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, shared_counter);

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
```

Some advice?

Comment: I think that GL_BLEND is used with transparency. Isn't it?

Comment: @zacharmarz I think it is also neccessary for `GL_LINE_SMOOTH` to work properly (which I think is what the OP wants, although "smoothness" is a bit vague a term).

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)` when you want to smooth out the colors between your primtitive's vertices. The initial value is `GL_SMOOTH`, so if you haven't changed it, you'll probably don't need to set it.

If you want smooth lines, use `glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH)`.

Answer (score -1):

Quite some time since i had the pleasure to play with opengl, but one thing comes to mind: Is it not necessary to specify the normals if you want your smooth shading?

Comment: Not if you don't use lighting

Comment: Answers are for answers, not further questions.